# Automatic redirection/rewriting of 1000 of old post urls in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, plugins, url-rewriting

Is there a way to do an automatic redirection of about 1000 posts to a new URL?
The old posts have dates in them that I want to be removed leaving only their unique post names.

Old URL: http://website.com/2015/11/post-name-etc/
New URL that I would like: http://website.com/post-name-etc/

Yoast Premium plugin has a redirection feature but it is only for one by one URL copy-pasting. I have looked at other redirect plugins and they all seem to be geared either towards one-by-one redirection or for future posts. C

Does anyone know about an automatic redirection plugin or can advise how to write a code in Java, Python, etc. that can do that for me? 
Thank you!

Comment: You should use .htaccess to redirect to new url.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Correct if I am wrong, but I would have to manually enter the old and the new URL for each of the 1000 posts. Is there a way to use .htaccess that would do it automatically for each of the URL addresses? My problem is quantity.